# What is instanceof of a cloned object?

Tags: java, clone

If a class *A* makes public Object's `clone()` method:

```
@Override
public Object clone() {
    return super.clone();
}
```

What will be the `instanceof` (or `getClass()`) of an instance of *A* created using `clone()`?
What about instances of `class B extends A` created using the `clone()` method ?

**EDIT**
Clarification: I ask this because even before compiling, Eclipse java editor **requires to cast** the returned clone() instance to the assigned object. Which suggest that the returned class is `Object` (which technically it is, but all the answers so far say the class should be A)

```
A original = new A();
A cloned1 = original.clone(); // Eclipse marks this as error
A cloned2 = (A) original.clone(); // This is OK
```

Comment: the answer is updated have a look!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same as the initiator by means the original parent class whic always uses Object.clone() by calling the super.clone(). For more visit

http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/11/08/a-guide-to-object-cloning-in-java/

https://www.artima.com/objectsandjava/webuscript/ClonCollInner1.html

Comment: Hi, is there any way you could summarise the subject matter of the links into your answer. It would make your answer considerably better and not reliant on external material, which could  be removed at any time. Thanks!

Comment: this post is has popped up in the review queue to be flagged or deleted. pls avoid link only answers. i have left a comment on few of your answers before also. Pls edit and elaborate or post links as comments since you have enough reputation

Answer (score 3):

It will be the same type as the original object as long as it uses `Object.clone()` by calling `super.clone()` and that ***should*** be done by [convention](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29).

Read the [doc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29).

This prints `String` but it is wrong by [convention](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29):

```
public class SomeTest {
    @Override
    protected Object clone() {
        return "";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new SomeTest().clone().getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It *should* be an instance of the parent class. But that relies on the implementer writing a conventional `clone` method.

In this, and other respects, cloning in Java is quite broken.